# How to find Distance Between Camera And Object

Tags: android, matrix, camera

I am new to this issue. I have requirement like this. I am making one application for an optician. He has such requirement that whenever any object **[I.E Customer of optician]** has come for eye test, on that time his photo should be captured,and after capturing photo, I need to measure distance between camera and object. As it is a part of some calculation of optician. How to measure distance between camera and object,of which image has been captured. Any Algorithm is available for that?

I have checked [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949777/how-can-we-measure-distance-between-object-and-android-phone-camera) but not getting what does it say.

If any one knows please guide me.

Comment: And what is a reason of downvotes? Already told that this issue is new to me,i describe what i found from google,y downvote?

Comment: The lazy way is to get some kind of object that you know the size, near  the customer.Then you do the math do find the size of the object in the image :/. Why don't you just integrate some arduino board with your application? http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-measure-distance-with-the-arduino.html

Comment: @GhostDerfel Thanks,let me read that documentation

Comment: This application is having similar functionality https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kr.aboy.tools and also there are couple of applications available on play store,Need to check how they have implemented