# How to find distance between object and camera when sensor changed using OpenCv?

Tags: java, android, opencv

I have working with object detection using openCV.I tried to find the angle between the object and the camera using accelerometer using this link;

[how can we measure distance between object and android phone camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949777/how-can-we-measure-distance-between-object-and-android-phone-camera)

The distance is changing but when i measured using scale its not showing correct value.Not even near to that value.

How can i find distance between object and camera using sensor.Thanks in advance.