# measure an object's height, width, distance through windows phones camera

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-8

I am completely new to windows phone development, I am planning to develop a windows phone 8 app that uses camera to measure an object's dimensions ie its height, width, distance from phone etc.

Is there any way in windows phone that makes it possible? I am fed up of searching for the topic but still with no results in my hand .. please tell me is it possible? if yes then how shall I proceed for it, what are the API's method's I am gonna use??
your help would be appreciated like anything..
thanks in advance

Comment: Possible? Sure. Feasible? Probably not. Just think about it. To get the dimensions, you need at least the distance and probably the angle. But how would you get the distance? The camera doesn't care how far away an object is. It basically just collects the photons reflected by it. You might be able to calculate the focal distance, but then again, thats just one point. You might get an accurate width or height for a flat side of an object that is absolutely parallel to the camera, but other than that, all bets are off. Maybe with several pics from several angles. A lot of mights and maybes.

Comment: thanks a lot sir!! Atleast I got a direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the Windows Phone doesn't include a sensor that will necessarily detect distances, as explained in this MSDN article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202968%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

However, with a clever use of trigonometry you might be able to combine the sensors capabilities to do so.

Here are the class library's documentation for each sensor:

Gyroscope:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202968%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Compass:

msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.devices.sensors.compass.aspx

And Accelerometer:

msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.devices.sensors.accelerometer.aspx

Best of luck!

Comment: If you remove the `en-us/` in the msdn links, you'll get the language independent version. And if you remove the `(v=vs.105)` part, you get the version independent... version. ^_^

Comment: Ah, will do! I can still only post two links because of my no-rep score. :)

Answer (score 0):

For messure distanse you need to use [simple mathematics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4589633/1616443) + [data from accelerometer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431810(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: accelerometer requires the phone in a moving state! I want my camera to focus on an object without movement, and get all these values calculated!! is it possible???

Comment: Sort answer - no. May be later, when new windows phones would be with 3d camera.., but not now.

Answer (score 0):

The answer appears currently to be "no", but contrary to what other (jimpanzer for example) would seem to indicate, this should be possible completely without any new hardware being added to the phone. The act of focusing your camera on an object would normally give the camera information on the distance to the subject focused on.

Take a look at any SLR lens of some quality, when you have focused on something, the lens has a distance scale on it, which will tell you how far away the entity which you are focusing on is. This distance would get less and less accurate the further away the object is, but, it *should* be possible for the camera to tell you approximately how far away an object you have focused on is.

So, I guess the answer, for those of us who would find this immensely useful, is to ask Microsoft/Nokia etc to provide this information in the camera API.