# Distance Moved in Video?

Tags: video, distance

I was wondering if this could be done given the following scenario and what resources are available to do this as simple as possible:

Say a rat is moving sideways in a chamber in a video (rectilinear motion), and the camera is set to take the full scope of the chamber. There is no background image or noise, and the rat is observed for a duration of time.

Is there anyway to define the distance along the tube in a video, for example, to be 5 meters, and then track the total distance traveled, not displacement, of the rat?

Comment: you also have to know the distance between camera and the object. if you be able to track object then you can use famous Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: Would that be necessary if the camera was at a perfectly straight side view and centered, with no elevation? 

Like for instance, I could define that walkway to be 10 yards, and assume distance is linearly spaced out along the frames. 

http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/side-view-street-sidewalk-36556971.jpg

Comment: yes. you need to know the distance anyway. but i dont think there is any way to find out distance from captured scene because its 2D scene. there is no information about 3rd dimension. but maybe there is some ways but not accurate. i really dont know way but i guess [this](http://www.topendsports.com/biomechanics/video-analysis-distance.htm) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588485/is-it-possible-to-measure-distance-to-object-with-camera) could help you.