# Android Camera - Distance between 2 points

Tags: android

I need a study resource or an answer to find out if it's possible for a Android Camera or the smartphone itself to calculate the distance between the smartphone and a wall (distance between 2 points).

Thank you

Comment: Have the user throw the phone at the wall then calculate velocity using the phone's sensors. Multiply by the time it took and you've got it! Assuming it survives the impact of course. (Otherwise, no there's nothing built-in as far as I know.)

Comment: The purpuse is to calculate the size of the wall (width x height). Any ideas on how i could get it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588485/is-it-possible-to-measure-distance-to-object-with-camera

Comment: Yes it is possible. you have to stick something onto the wall, where you know exactly how big it is. You could take a square or to dots where you know the difference. But it is not build into android.