# How to get the distance from an object to android device using camera2 API

Tags: android, android-camera2

I want to get the distance from an object to android device using android camera2 API. In `CaptureCallback`, I get the value by `result.get(CaptureResult.LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE)` and check `LENS_STATE, CONTROL_AF_MODE, CONTROL_AF_STATE` at the same time. They are "STATIONARY", `CONTINUOUS_PICTURE` and `PASSIVE_FOCUSED`. I think the focus distance should be valid and the distance from an object to android device should be `1/focus_distance`. But in fact the calculated value is totally different from the actual distance. What's wrong with it? Is `LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE` the correct value for distance estimation? Anyone have idea?

```
final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureCallbackListener = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {
        super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
        Log.e(TAG, String.format("captureCallbackListener %s-%f", lensStateToString(result.get(CaptureResult.LENS_STATE)), result.get(CaptureResult.LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE) ));
        Log.e(TAG, String.format("AF mode %s-%s", ctlAfModeToString(result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_MODE)), ctlAfStateToString(result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE)) ));
    }
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to measure distance to object with camera?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588485/is-it-possible-to-measure-distance-to-object-with-camera)

Comment: To avoid down vote, try to search your queries first and then post the question

Answer (score 4):

Please check the value of [CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INFO_FOCUS_DISTANCE_CALIBRATION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#LENS_INFO_FOCUS_DISTANCE_CALIBRATION).  If it's UNCALIBRATED or APPROXIMATE, then the value of LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE will likely not be close to reality.

And even with CALIBRATED, the farther objects are, the more error there will be - to the camera, everything past the hyperfocal distance (a few meters at best) starts being impossible to accurately measure distance to.